# "No database selected" when running procedures

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hello there I am new to all of this and recently took over my cricket teams website. I have been doing this procedure for 3 month without any problem but today this happened when I ran this query in the SQL section:

```
CALL refresh_batting_profile_snapshot(@rc);
CALL refresh_bowling_profile_snapshot(@rc);
CALL refresh_mvp_snapshot();
CALL refresh_mvp_derived_moms();
```

The error message I got back was this:

```
CALL refresh_batting_profile_snapshot(@rc)
);
```

MySQL said:

```
1046 - No database selected
```

Comment: It's not a problem with your stored procedure; apparently your code is no longer selecting the database.

Comment: Well, if you haven't changed the code it can also mean that you're calling the procedure from the wrong place. Typically if you're running this from phpmyadmin, this means it works only if you select a database first before runnning the query.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a database list in the left pane. Click on the one you want to use in order to select it:

[image: Database pane]

One you do that, the SQL pane will reflect the currently selected database:

[image: SQL pane]

Comment: For the complete solution, note that you can run these stored procedures from within phpMyAdmin -- click the "Routines" tab instead of the SQL one for access to the graphical interface to Routines.

Comment: Thanks so much Guys that really helped and i have now managed to do it without any problem :)